# How to pass dynamic props to vue's render function?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-render-function

I try to render components dynamically based on descriptions.
From

```
{component: 'customComponent', props: {value: "val1"}, ...}
```

I'd render

```
<custom-component :value="val1" @input="v=>val1=v" />`
```

I aim to do this for arbitrary events and dynamic props.
I have no idea though how to pass dynamic props to render.

**Partial solution:**

A solution that works but re-renders everytime `val1` changes, based on (https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/vue/vue-instance) is

```
render: function(h){
    const template = "...building up the html here..."
    return Vue.compile(template).render.call(this, h);
}
```

**My attempt using the VueJS docs**

I could not find in the [docs on render](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) how I could pass dynamic variables.

In the minimal implementation you can see how far I've got, if you can help me finish it, it would be awesome!

**Minimal implementation so far**

I expect to see 'hello' instead of 'values.value1' and values.value1 should update once I change the text in the text box.

demo.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="q-app">
    The text input should say 'hello' instead of 'values.value1'
    <custom-component :descriptor="mainComponent"></custom-component>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@^2.0.0/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.15.15/dist/quasar.umd.min.js"></script>
  <script>
Vue.component('custom-component', {
    props: ['descriptor'],
    render: function (createElement) {
        const attributes = {
            on: this.descriptor.events,
            props: this.descriptor.props
        }
        return createElement(
            this.descriptor.component,
            attributes)
    }
})
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#q-app',
    data: function(){
    return {
        mainComponent: {
           component: 'q-input',
           props: {
               value: 'values.value1'
           },
           events: {
               input: value => this.values.value1 = value
           }
        },
        values: {
            value1: 'hello'
        }
    }
  }
})
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: If you're rendering components dynamically, shouldn't you be using `v-bind:is`?

Comment: @Terry, thanks for looking into this! I'm open to using `v-bind:is` as well, when I tried that <component :is="descriptor.component" v-bind="descriptor.props" /> I had no luck binding the variable. Do you know how I can bind by ref there?

Comment: Ah, I remember now, why I could not use `v-bind:is`! Although there is `v-bind="props"`, but there is no `v-on="events"`.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share a minimal, concrete and verifiable example?

Comment: Sure, I have updated my question. If you just copy-paste it to say demo.html, you can see that it displays 'values.value1' instead of 'hello' and that is what I'd expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, I have fixed your example.

Of course, you can `watch` the value in the main app. But it is better to sent an `input` event with the value.

Added the reference to the component

```
ref="mc"
```

and the `input` event binding

```
@input="logEventValue"
```

```js
Vue.component('custom-component', {
    props: ['descriptor'],
    render: function (createElement) {
        const attributes = {
            on: this.descriptor.events,
            props: this.descriptor.props
        }
        return createElement(
            this.descriptor.component,
            attributes)
    }
})
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#q-app',
    data: function(){      
      return {
          mainComponent: {
             component: 'q-input',
             props: {
                 value: 'hello'
             },
             events: {              
               input: value => {
                  this.values.value1 = value;
                  // with ref="mc" 
                  this.$refs.mc.$emit('input', value); 
                  // or over the list of children
                  this.$children[0].$emit('input', value); 
                }
             }  
          },
          values: {
            value1: 'hello'
        }
      }
   },   
   watch: {
      'values.value1': (newVal) => console.log(`1. watcher: ${newVal}`),
      // or deeply
      values: {
        handler(newVal) {
            console.log(`2. watcher: ${newVal.value1}`)
        },
        deep: true,
      }
   },
   methods: {
      logEventValue(value) {
        console.log(`logEventValue: ${value}`);
      }
   }
})
```

```html
<div id="q-app">
  <custom-component ref="mc" @input="logEventValue" :descriptor="mainComponent"></custom-component>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@^2.0.0/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.15.15/dist/quasar.umd.min.js"></script>
```